# WooCommerce Variable product with variations, but with different files and same attributes

Tags: woocommerce, download, attributes

I want to sell software licenses and I have problem with having a couple of file extensions for same attribute.

For example, from 1st dropdown visitor selects OS: Windows, Android, Mac...
From 2nd dropdown, visitor selects number of users: 1 user, 5 users...
And from 3rd dropdown he have only one option: Software

For example, when visitor selects:
Windows > 1 user > Software and make payment, visitor should get download link for EXE file.
Android > 1 user > Software and make payment, visitor should get download link for APK file.

The problem is with attribute for Software – I need to upload 3 file types under same attribute (EXE, APK...).

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the thank you page and then loop through the ordered variations and output the relevant links if the correct product had been purchased - something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'addDownloadLinksToThankyou' );
  
function addDownloadLinksToThankyou( $order_id ) {

// Getting an instance of the order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// loop through purchased items
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    
    // assume this item isn't the software
    $softwarePurchased = false;
    
    // get the id of the current item in loop
    $item_id = $item->get_id();
    $product_id = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_id', true);
    
    // if the item is the software product
    if($product_id == *INSERT MAIN PROD ID*){
        $softwarePurchased = true;
    }

    // if the order is defo paid and this item is the software
    if($order->is_paid() && $softwarePurchased){

    if( $item->is_type('variable') ) {
      $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
   }

    //Logic here, if $variation_id == *variationid for android* output link to download APK else if $variation_id == *variationid for Mac* etc..

    }
}
}
```